Lerna returns 0 found packages
After upgrading lerna from 7 to 8.1.7, I can no longer build my project which resides in a mono-repo.
It seems to not find the dependencies of the various packages.
$ npx lerna list returns found 0 packages while $ npx lerna clean cleans the node_modules in every single package present in my monorepo...
A bit more stranger : yarn workspaces info shows my packages with the correct dependencies between them...
Even stranger, the update hasn't affected a single other colleague in my team and the build runs flawlessly both on github ci/cd and my second computer...
I also created a "test" project from scratch and I have the exact same issue...
Here is how I set it up :
root package.json
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "name": "lernatest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "lerna": "^8.1.7"
  }
}

first package :
{
  "name": "patata",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "echo \"build patata\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "patato": "1.0.0"
  }
}

second package :
{
  "name": "patato",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "echo \"build patatb\""
  }
}

lerna.json
{
  "$schema": "node_modules/lerna/schemas/lerna-schema.json",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "npmClient": "yarn"
}

I'm starting to get a seriously lost, but I'd guess it has something to do with my config or something... Any lead ? Please ?
More infos :
node v20.16.0
yarn 1.22.22
lerna 8.1.7
already cleared yarn cache,
already removed ~/.yarn,
already double checked permissions,
already executed $ npx lerna clean,
already cloned a fresh one on another location.

it might be related to this opened issue, on the other hand if you're not using Nx then you might give Lerna-Lite a try, which is a lighter version of Lerna without Nx and closer to the original code (before Nrwl took over and added Nx on top of Lerna)

Thanks for your lead. Just tried it, and indeed it - at least - work as you'd expect. Will switch to lerna-lite.
